# How to decrement multiple record with same Id in different date

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some record in one table that have same Id but different date and volume.

```
Id | Date       | Name | Volume
1  | 01/08/2019 | Item | 2
1  | 02/08/2019 | Item | 3
1  | 03/08/2019 | Item | 5
```

Then I have a selling form that will decrease the volume each time user sell Item.

I want it to be this way :
When user sells 7 Item in one time, the decrement is going to be like this

```
Id | Date       | Name | Volume
1  | 01/08/2019 | Item | 0
1  | 02/08/2019 | Item | 0
1  | 03/08/2019 | Item | 3
```

It is starting from the oldest date, and when volume on the date not enough it will decrease the next oldest date

But I don't know how to do the loop.

Comment: Your example data doesn't have any records with the same id?

Comment: edited it, sorry

Comment: Please format your data - you've just edited back over some kind people who formatted it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Id INT,
  Date DATE,
  Name VARCHAR(45),
  Volume INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, '2019-08-01', 'Item', 2),
(1, '2019-08-02', 'Item', 3),
(1, '2019-08-03', 'Item', 5);

SELECT *, CASE WHEN SUM(Volume) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date) < V THEN 0
               ELSE SUM(Volume) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date) - V
               END Result
FROM T CROSS JOIN (VALUES(7)) TT(V);
```

If you're going to `UPDATE` the table:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN SUM(Volume) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date) < V THEN 0
                 ELSE SUM(Volume) OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date) - V
                 END Result
  FROM T CROSS JOIN (VALUES(7)) TT(V)
)
UPDATE T
SET Volume = CTE.Result
FROM T JOIN CTE
ON T.Id = CTE.Id
   AND
   T.Date = CTE.Date;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4c53a7914e430c549e2246f6861b5ccc)**

---

UPDATE:

Here is a new query using a Correlated subquery

```
WITH A AS
(
  SELECT *,
         (
           SELECT SUM(TT.Volume)
           FROM T TT
           WHERE TT.Id = T.Id
                 AND
                 TT.Date <= T.Date
                 AND
                 T.Volume >= TT.Volume
         ) R
  FROM T
)
SELECT T.*, CASE WHEN R < 7 THEN 0 ELSE R - 7 END Result
FROM T JOIN A 
ON T.Id = A.Id AND T.[Date] = A.[Date];
```

**[Demo for the Correlated subquery](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1c0986d3735829f4e0c92c736b4931d3)**

Comment: what is TT(V) ?

Comment: @Keanu1701 It's a table contains the count of sold items, you can remove it and use `7` directly instead of `V` column just like **[this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1044fbb3be96c7c49bd2e95106fb2144)**

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'Result'.

Comment: Did you check the link I just give you @Keanu1701? cause it works just fine to me unless you have something you don't tell about it. Wrap the columns in `[]`

Comment: Yes I do, it's work fine in browser code editor, I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: @Keanu1701 Check the updates, and please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Try code like below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication124
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Volume", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, DateTime.Parse("08/01/2019"), "Item", 2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, DateTime.Parse("08/02/2019"), "Item", 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, DateTime.Parse("08/03/2019"), "Item", 5 });

            dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date")).CopyToDataTable();

            int order = 7;

            foreach(DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Id") == 1))
            {


                int oldVolume = row.Field<int>("Volume");

                if (oldVolume >= order)
                {
                    row["Volume"] =  row.Field<int>("Volume") - order;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    order -= oldVolume;
                    row["Volume"] = 0;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it using EF?

Comment: I  just put the data into a DataTable.  Entity uses DataTable as well.  You would just have to replace the dt in my code with the entity table name.